# how to replace/append text between a pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ejs

I want to repave a string in between a pattern

**suppose my input string is**

```
var st= "include('sometxt.abc')";
var st2 = "include('somename.xyz')";
```

and I want to replace the text inside each and every include for example **my outputs for the above inputs will be**

```
"include('folder/sometext.abc')"
"include('folder/sometxt.abc')"
```

however, I am able to search the string using pattern but don't know how to replace,
and the **search pattern is**

```
/include\("\w+.\w+"\)/g
```

thnakyou.

Comment: You should capture less of the text and use a capture group. regex: `(include\(')` replace: `$1folder/`. See https://regex101.com/r/5RiwLL/1/ and use the code generator button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some remarks:

- Your regex does not match the examples, because of the different quote.
- filenames can have characters other than matched by `\w`. This is probably too constraining.

You can use capture groups to match the parts before and after the insertion point (for "folder/"). You can use a back reference to require that the opening and closing quote are of the same type.

We could imagine more checks, but with those ingredients you can do:

```js
var input = `include('sometxt.abc')
include('somename.xyz')`;

let result = input.replace(/(\binclude\((['"]))(\S+\.\S+\2\))/g, "$1folder/$3");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get the position where you want to insert the text.

```
/(?=[a-zA-Z]+?\.)/
```

[image]

```js
var st = "include('sometxt.abc')";
var st2 = "include('somename.xyz')";

const result = st.replace(/(?=[a-zA-Z]+?\.)/, "folder/");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to insert something *before* the *first* `'`, why not use `indexOf` to get the index of that char, and then use `substr` to 'insert' it after that char?

Example:

```js
var st= "include('sometxt.abc')";
var st2 = "include('somename.xyz')";

console.log(insert(st));
console.log(insert(st2));

function insert(to, what = 'folder/') {
  let posOfFirstQuote = to.indexOf("'") + 1;
  return to.substr(0, posOfFirstQuote) + what + to.substr(posOfFirstQuote);
}
```

Comment: I have used `st` and `st2` variables just for example and simplification for question, in my original string there can be more of `'` and `"` however, thankyou for answering my question.